# Query json column based on the integer value in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I am using postgres v9.3

I have a table called temp which have a column all_data. The value looks something like below :-

```
{"Accountid" : "1364", "Personalid" : "4629-87c3-04e6a7a60208", "quote_number" : "QWQA62364384"}
```

Now, I want to query the all_data column by accountid=1364.

Could you please tell what would be the query?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`->>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

```
select *
from temp
where all_data ->> 'Accountid' = '1364';
```

Online example for 9.3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55981/1

However the above will not work if the JSON contains an array instead of a JSON object. E.g. a value like `'[1,2]'::json` will cause that query to fail.

With 9.4 and above you could check that using `json_typeof()` but with your soon to be unsupported version the only workaround I can think of is to convert the column to text and exclude those that start with a `[`

```
with valid_rows as (
  select *
  from temp
  where all_data::text not like '[%'
)
select *
from valid_rows
where all_data ->> 'Accountid' = '1364';
```

Online example for 9.3: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d01f43/3

Comment: Error : cannot extract field from a non-object
I am using postgres v 9.3

Comment: I guess if it's not proper then it should not allow to store JSON data as well.

Comment: Yes, i saw the output and it's working for you. Provided in the question is exactly how the data stored in column. What could be the other cause of this error?

Comment: @Nik: check the fiddle for 9.3 and compare that with your table definition.

Comment: I got it. I believe it's probably because of data inconsistency. Some fields are null and some are inserted as "AccountID". I believe this can be the cause. Also could you please add single quote after 1364 so that i can accept the answer. Also if you could add that data inconsistency may not work, it will be great.

Comment: Could you please try to insert 2-3 rows with value 'null' (with single quote) and check whether you are able to fetch.

Comment: `'null'` isn't a valid JSON value. You can't store that in a JSON column